# Positive operator implications

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, definition

Given the following statement from a text "*Positive operators $A$ have a complete set of eigenvectors, and all their eigenvalues are non-negative. This implies that a positive operator $A$ is Hermitian.*"

As I understand there are different conventions for defining what a 'positive operator' is. In this context it does not seem sufficient to consider that it is a positive semi-definite, this implies non-negative eigenvalues but not necessarily a complete set of eigenvectors and not necessarily Hermitian. What definition of positive does this statement suggest?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Positive operators are generally required to be Hermitian. You could define a notion of positivity for non-Hermitian matrices, by indeed simply requiring that its eigenvalues are non-negative. But this is not really a pleasant definition. For example, with this definition you can imagine two "positive" non-Hermitian matrices but with a sum that isn't a positive matrix.

Comment: @Demophilus Thanks for your response. From the quoted part of my question, can you see why this implies that $A$ would  be Hermitian? Also how would you define positive operators in this context?

Comment: I'm wondering in what text you encountered this (arguably wrong) definition?

Comment: @Demophilus It was actually from a set of lecture notes from a physics course (that might indicate the lack of rigor). Does $A$ having a complete set of eigenvectors, and all their eigenvalues are non-negative imply hermiticity, I can't see how that would be true...

Comment: It doesn't imply Hermiticity, I provided a counter example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more complete answer than my comment.
I believe the notion positivity as defined in your quote can't make sense.
Consider the following matrix
$$
A = \left( \begin{matrix} 2 & 0  \\
1 & 1\end{matrix}\right).
$$
Note that the two eigenvectors
$$\left( \begin{matrix} 0   \\
1 \end{matrix}\right),\left( \begin{matrix} 1   \\
1 \end{matrix}\right),
$$
have eigenvalues $1$ and $2$. The eigenvectors span the entire space, so it's a matrix with a complete set of eigenvectors and non-negative eigenvalues. Yet it is non-Hermitian. As explained in my comment, being Hermitian is a very desired property for positive matrices to have.

Comment: Okay I see thanks. So the definition should include that the operator is Hermitian. What would be your definition of a positive operator?

Comment: The most elegant I believe is the following: $A$ is positive if and only if $A = B^\dagger B$ where $B$ is any matrix and $\dagger$ denotes the Hermitian conjugate. I like this definition since it can be easily generalised to $C^*$-algebras, where there is no mention of an inner product.